# Why we use Pre order , Post order techniques for trees even though we can traverse with In order

Tags: graph-theory

My question is about tree methods that why we use Pre order and  Post order techniques for trees even though we can traverse with In order

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. For any particular problem to be solved, generally one of those orderings will result in us visiting tree nodes in the "correct" order and either of the alternatives will not. One of the orderings isn't inherently better or more natural than the others

Comment: quick answer : If you want to delete nodes, you use post-order. If you want to have the path from root to leaf, use pre-order.